# Unable to launch a PDF viewer in Nougat (7.1)

Tags: android

I am creating a app in which i am generating pdf and after this app showing PDF  automatically. it is working wee in 6.1 android but not showing in android 7.1. my code is

```
public void showPDF() {

    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "A_DailyRegiser.pdf");

    try {
        if (pdfFile.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
            Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
           // objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            objIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            objIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(objIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(dailycollection.this, "File NotFound",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        Toast.makeText(dailycollection.this,

                "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

 }
```

Comment: Could you show error log?

Comment: Your code is using `file://` uri in android 7 which results into the error you are facing, you should change your `targetSdk` to lower version than 24 or use `FileProvider` and share your uri

Comment: no error showing

Comment: can u please provide sample code for FileProvider

Comment: You are not getting an error because that exception ([FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html)) is being caught in your code, I would advise you to checkout the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) documentation to understand it better if you want to implement it in your app

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the new changes in Noughat API's Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html)

you are suggested to use the `content://` scheme instead of `file://` for this we can use the [file provider API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html).

here is sample code:

```
<manifest>
...
<application>
    ...
     <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
    ...
</application>
```

define the scope of your access

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
```

Generating the Content URI for a File

```
File imagePath = new File(Context.getFilesDir(), "images");
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "default_image.jpg");
Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile);
```

Granting Temporary Permissions to a URI

```
 Intent.setFlags() with either FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or both.
```

read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)